# Cannot remove a file after its transfer was interrupted (on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 SP1)

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I was copying files from linux to windows (via COPSSH) using a command like (from linux shell):

```
scp -pr dir administrator@win:/cygdrive/c/dest/
```

(dir was a directory with files and subdirectories)

Transfer was interrupted by pressing ctrl-c (from linux shell). I was able to delete all the files copied to windows except the one which transfer was interrupted on and (sub)directories in which it resides.

How can I delete this file?

In security settings of this file as current owner is "Unable to display current owner". I tried (of course as administrator) to change ownership of this file to administrator, but always got "Access is denied". I also tried this as SvcCOPSSH user (copSSH service account) and as sshd (copSSH privilege separation user) but that as well didn't succeed.
That command didn't do the job either:

```
takeown /F file /A
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Administrative Tools, Computer Management, System Tools, Shared Folders, Open Files. Close the open file connection.

Or reboot Windows. If there is an existing connection, shut-down will close it.

Or leave it for a while. If there is no connection, or if the connection is using BITs, the open file will timeout after a while.

Does SCP use Background Intelligent Transfer? (Unlikely). If so, use BITSadmin.

Comment: I was able to delete this file after rebooting Windows. As far as I can tell it was caused by some process keeping file handles opened just as it was pointed out here: http://serverfault.com/questions/9302/security-unable-to-display-current-owner?rq=1